# Can Civilization 2 be modded/patched to always allow all research options?

Tags: civilization-2

In Civilization 2 (Specifically ''Civ2: Multiplayer Gold Edition'') is there some way you can edit the rules.txt or something to make it so that when you've given the options to select a tech it will always allow you to select every tech you have the requirements for?

Specifically, when starting a new game, I usually research Code of Laws and Ceremonial Burial, but then Monarchy won't show up right away, and I'll have to research something else before I can research Monarchy.

And it's just really annoying.

Comment: I seem to remember there being an option for this, but I can't recall if I'm thinking of Civ2 or one of the other Civ games.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All technologies for which you have the prerequisites are always available when you're playing a scenario.

So the way to get around the restriction is turn your regular game into a scenario. That is quite easy to do. As soon as you started your game, showing your blinking settler, open the ***Cheat*** menu, choose ***Toggle Cheat Mode*** and confirm. Then pick the last item in the cheat menu, ***Save As Scenario***. As soon as you've saved it, ***Quit*** the game and open your newly saved scenario from the main menu using ***Begin Scenario***.

The only information you get to see about your game that you normally wouldn't is who your opponents are, since you have to pick who to play when you start the scenario. Also, your game may get scored differently or end up being marked as a scenario if it ends up in the Hall of Fame (I forgot how that works), but other than that the game should play about the same. Except of course, that you can choose among all technologies.

If you think this is too much, well, *cheating*, maybe you'll find it interesting to know that [there's a pattern to which technologies exactly are unavailable. You can find the details described here: http://apolyton.net/showthread.php/2512

In short, depending on the number of technologies you have researched, about one third of all technologies are made unavailable. To be more precise, that is done according to the following table:

```
2 Advanced Flight      0 Alphabet           1 Amphibious Warfare
2 Astronomy            0 Atomic Theory      1 Automobile
2 Banking              0 Bridge Building    1 Bronze Working
2 Ceremonial Burial    0 Chemistry          1 Chivalry
2 Code of Laws         0 Combined Arms      1 Combustion
2 Communism            0 Computers          1 Conscription
2 Construction         0 The Corporation    1 Currency
2 Democracy            0 Economics          1 Electricity
2 Electronics          0 Engineering        1 Environmentalism
2 Espionage            0 Explosives         1 Feudalism
2 Flight               0 Fundamentalism     1 Fusion Power
2 Genetic Engineering  0 Guerrilla Warfare  1 Gunpowder
2 Horseback Riding     0 Industrialization  1 Invention
2 Iron Working         0 Labor Union        1 The Laser
2 Leadership           0 Literacy           1 Machine Tools
2 Magnetism            0 Map Making         1 Masonry
2 Mass Production      0 Mathematics        1 Medicine
2 Metallurgy           0 Miniaturization    1 Mobile Warfare
2 Monarchy             0 Monotheism         1 Mysticism
2 Navigation           0 Nuclear Fission    1 Nuclear Power
2 Philosophy           0 Physics            1 Plastics
2 Plumbing             0 Polytheism         1 Pottery
2 Radio                0 Railroad           1 Recycling
2 Refining             0 Refrigeration      1 The Republic
2 Robotics             0 Rocketry           1 Sanitation
2 Seafaring            0 Space Flight       1 Stealth
2 Steam Engine         0 Steel              1 Superconductor
2 Tactics              0 Theology           1 Theory of Gravity
2 Trade                0 University         1 Warrior Code
2 The Wheel            0 Writing
```

If you have not researched any technologies yet (not counting those you got for free at the start), all technologies *except the first one that's available* (i.e. for which you have the prerequisites) in the second column (marked with zeroes) will be unresearchable. After you discovered one technology, the technologies in the third column become unavailable (except the first one). With two technologies it's the technologies in the first column that are affected. When you have three technologies you're back to missing technologies from the second column etc.